# Php calculate char in string unique and occurance

Tags: javascript, php

I written previously to calculate for client using javascript

This is my function

```
var check = {}, string = inputString, count = 0;
var occurrence;
$.each(string.split(''), function(){
    if(!check[this]){
        count++;
        check[this]=true;
})
```

The function above I use it to calculate number occurrence in a string

For example

```
number 1234 will return 4, as there are number 1,2,3 and 4
number 1233 will return 3, as the unique number are 1,2 and 3
number 1212 will return 2, as the unique number are 1 and 2
```

I wonder how do I convert my function above into a working php function that return the same count.

The next thing is I written another check which is getMostOccurrence

The purpose is for example

```
number 1212, will return 2, as 1 appear 2 times, and 2 appear 2 times
```

However if number

```
1112, the result will be 3, as 1 appear 3 times
```

How do I do this count function in php

**Thanks for helping!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)**

> Counts the number of occurrences of every byte-value (0..255) in string and returns it in various ways.

Example taken straight from **[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)**

```
<?php
$data = "Two Ts and one F.";

foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string.\n";
}
?>
```

You can use it to fulfil your second purpose very easily as well.

Comment: I used count char and they give me this There were 1 instance(s) of "A" in the string. There were 1 instance(s) of "a" in the string. There were 2 instance(s) of "r" in the string. There were 1 instance(s) of "y" in the string. for 1234